# Running Fabric with Python script together

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

I see most of the Fabric API are use together with function.

Example of file (sample.py):

```
from fabric.api import *
print "Hello"

def deploy():
    with settings(hosts_string="Remote", user = "ubuntu", key_filename="/home/ubuntu/key.pem"):
        put('/home/localuser/sample.sh', '/home/ubuntu/')
        run('bash /home/ubuntu/sample.sh')
```

I run the command to execute

```
fab deploy
```

Is it possible to running Fabric in Main Method. So when I run it as a python script, the fabric will be executed.

```
python ./sample.py
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To answer your question directly, you can add this snippet to your file:

```
from fabric.api import *
print "Hello"

def deploy():
    with settings(host_string="Remote", user = "ubuntu", key_filename="/home/ubuntu/key.pem"):
        put('/home/localuser/sample.sh', '/home/ubuntu/')
        run('bash /home/ubuntu/sample.sh')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   deploy()
```

Now when you run `python ./sample.py`, it will do the same thing as `fab deploy`

However, the `fab` allows you to do much more other than your simple example. See the [fab documentation](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.3.2/usage/fab.html) for more information on the flexibility of the `fab` command.

Comment: think the settings argument should be 'host_string' (not plural)

Answer (score 0):

You have to give fabric's execute command. At the very bottom execute(deploy)